# webservice and asp

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services

I created a asp page. Also I created a asp.net web service. And I caught this webservice response using javascript in asp page. But I got that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<string xmlns="http://localhost/DevTrack4U">**True**</string>
```

I want to get the value that is **True**. But I got like this. How can I retrieve this.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://MyPathToWebServiceGoesHere/",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        var myString = $(xml).find('string').text();
}
});
```

This code will work if there is only one "string" element. FWIW, I suggest using a more descriptive name than "string".

Comment: I cannot use jQuery. I want to use pure javascript.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't use jQuery? I need to understand why you can't use a library that reduces this problem from 50 lines of code to 1.

Comment: Because I already used classic asp page and vb script. So, I will catch this value from javascript and I will transfer to vbscript code.

Comment: Ok, so there's not a way to "transfer to vbscript code" at this point unless you're planning on doing a post of the data back to the web service with another call. By the time you retrieve the value in javascript, the browser (client) has the output from the server. There is no more code that can be output on the page. If you need to output this value on the asp page using vbscript, you need to make the web service call inside your asp code and process it server-side.